# DHCPv6 Relay Agent on Juniper — Packets dropped: No SAFD

Tags: juniper, juniper-junos, dhcpv6

I tried to setup a DHCPv6 relay agent on a Juniper EX3400 switch. (SLAAC is unfortunately not enough for this use case.)

While the setup of the (non-v6) DHCP relay agent worked flawlessly and was well-documented [[1]](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/task/configuration/security-dhcp-relay-agent-minimum-configuration.html)[[2]](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/us/en/software/junos/dhcp/topics/topic-map/dhcp-relay-agent-security-devices.html), the DHCPv6-part of manual [[3]](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/us/en/software/junos/dhcp/topics/topic-map/dhcpv6-relay-agent.html) is rather brief in my opinion.

It more or less just mentions the `dhcpv6`-keyword and a few things that are specific to v6. So, I just took the non-v6 config and reused it under the `dhcpv6`-keyword. Since the auto-completion in JunOS knew all those keywords, I guess that is how it is intended anyhow.

The relevant part of the config thus now looks like this:

```
[edit forwarding-options dhcp-relay dhcpv6]
relay-agent-option-79;
group default {
    interface irb.100;
}
server-group {
    dhcpv6-servers {
        2001:db8::1;
        2001:db8::2;
    }
}
active-server-group dhcpv6-servers;
```

However, that does not seem to be enough. Apparently, the switch now drops all DHCPv6 packets:

```
user@junos> show dhcpv6 relay statistics 
Dhcpv6 Packets dropped:
    Total                 133
    No SAFD               133

Messages received:
    DHCPV6_DECLINE             0
    DHCPV6_SOLICIT             0
    DHCPV6_INFORMATION_REQUEST 0
    DHCPV6_RELEASE             0
    DHCPV6_REQUEST             0
    DHCPV6_CONFIRM             0
    DHCPV6_RENEW               0
    DHCPV6_REBIND              0
    DHCPV6_RELAY_FORW          0
    DHCPV6_LEASEQUERY_REPLY    0
    DHCPV6_LEASEQUERY_DATA     0
    DHCPV6_LEASEQUERY_DONE     0

Messages sent:
    DHCPV6_ADVERTISE           0
    DHCPV6_REPLY               0
    DHCPV6_RECONFIGURE         0
    DHCPV6_RELAY_REPL          0
    DHCPV6_LEASEQUERY          0
```

According to the docs [[4]](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/us/en/software/junos/subscriber-mgmt-sessions/topics/ref/command/show-dhcpv6-relay-statistics.html), "No SAFD" means the ports on which the DHCPv6 request came in are not configured:

> - **No SAFD** — Number of packets discarded because they arrived on an unconfigured interface.

But the packets come in via access ports that are a member of the VLAN assigned to `irb.100` and for non-v6, mentioning `interface irb.100` under the `group`-keyword is all that is necessary to trust these interfaces.

What am I missing here? How can I get the switch to accept the `DHCPV6_REQUEST` packets?

Comment: Dumb question: does irb.100 have a configured IPv6 address?

Comment: @Zac67 Yes, IPv6 address for the switch itself is configured too under `interfaces irb unit 100 family inet6`.